# How to change color depth in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: command-line, server, color-depth

I was learning vim editor from ssh terminal and messing with syntax highlighting and colorschemes and noticed my console colors were way off.

I can test 256 colors in PuTTy using,

`echo -e "\033[38;5;208m This is orange text\033[0m"`

but only the 8 colors in console.

Comment: Are you asking about SSH or the TTY?

Comment: @muru The TTy console, TERM=linux. I don't see anyway to change it, but I can run tmux and vi inside tmux and end up with 256 colors in vim that way.

Comment: Seems you'll have to use fbterm then https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254249/70524